# Mysql Too many connection in WAMP

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I run the following command :

Show status like "conn%"

connections = 160,000

1. restart the WAMP
2. closed the browsers with my apps that talking to DB (using php)
3. restart Wamp again
4. still the connection is continues to rise .

if I using medoo framework in php and PDO  the connection is closed when the script is finished?

Comment: do you close the connection after opening it ? 
it may be happen because of repeating opening the database

Comment: As the duplicate topic describes, you misunderstood the meaning of the connections status variable.